# Can py2exe keep a py file as configure script?

Tags: python, py2exe

I want to distribute a python program as an executable file. I use py2exe with `options = {"py2exe":{"bundle_files": 1}}`. But I want to keep a py file as configure script ( including not just variables but also functions and classes ).

Can py2exe do this? Or any other way to do it?

Comment: So... you want `py2exe` to **not** package everything into an `exe`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen the python program include dozens of py files. I want package everything into a exe but a configure file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can if you exec () the contents of the .py file.